# Add Image in Email From field

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-13

In odoo 13 i have a field example:

```
birthday_picture = fields.Image(string='Birthday Picture')
```

i want to add `birthday_picture` image to be added in email template also which i declared in xml,
i have added `<img>` tag and added still the image is not reflecting below i have shared the line

```
<div>
    <img src="${'/birthday_picture.png=%s' % object.birthday_picture}" style="width: 60px; height: 60px"/><br/>
</div>
```

please let me know where i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i have added this:

```
<p>
    <img src="/web/image/birthday.reminder/${object.id}/birthday_picture/"/>
</p>
```

which doesnot reflect the image in template but when i looked for undelivered email from `techncal > email`. by removing `force_send` from code i can see my image reflected on it.

**however i already searched that the email doesnot support `base64` images but there is a tweak to do it as well. here is the [link](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/how-to-send-image-in-email-template-123129) which descried the tweak**

Answer (score 1):

If `birthday_picture` must be dynamic (this means the same email template may render different images) you should consider using `fields.Binary`

`fields.Binary` stores a binary file in `odoo filesystem` and returns a base64 encoded string.

```
birthday_picture = fields.Binary(string='Birthday Picture')
<img src="${'data:image/png;base64,%s' % object.birthday_picture}" style="width: 60px; height: 60px"/>
```

In case `birthday_pictur`e is always the same (so it is static) best solution would be to create an `ir.attachment`, set it as public and render into `src` it's url

Another option would be to manually convert your file into base64 using an online tool and replace `src` value with the encoded string.

Comment: Yes Brother i want the image dynamically, and as you sid above i did try this but still doesnot return image which i provide in binary field

Comment: Can you debug email raw body in order to understand what it is printing instead of the base64 string? Also are you sure the model selected in `mail.template` is the same model where you added `birthday_picture` field? Try printing `object.birthday_picture` into the email template to further investigate

Comment: yeah i am sure `birthday_picture` is in the same model as provided in `mail.template`, also i already checked what is printing instead of base64 string, it is printing the binary format of the image.

Comment: This means binary data must be first converted to base64. You can use `image_data_uri` or `to_text` qweb helper functions to obtain this. For example: `${'data:image/png;base64,%s' % image_data_uri(object.birthday_picture)}`

Comment: No still i cannot see the template to reflect the image however i already solved that